# "an internal error occurred" when using AES encryption algorithm with OFB cipher mode

Tags: vb.net, encryption, aes

I am working for a project (using vb.net 4.5) which have to use AES encryption using a key (will be provided as input parameter for the function)

I have tried to use the following code

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
Public Class EncryptionFunction
    Public Function DoEncryption(ByVal keyByte() As Byte, IV() As Byte)
        Dim a As Aes = Aes.Create
        a.Mode = CipherMode.OFB

        Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform

        encryptor = a.CreateEncryptor(keyByte, IV)


    End Function
End Class
```

but an error occurred in the

> encryptor = a.CreateEncryptor(keyByte, IV)

the error is "an internal error occurred" , if I change the cipher mode it works correctly but I have to use OFB mode.

so , any suggestions?

Comment: when I tried to run the same code on another machine it worked correctly!!
My machine (Windows 8.1 , .net framework 4.5 and visual studio 2012), The other machine(Windows 8  .net framework 4.5 and visual studio 2012)
so what is the problem on my machine? help me please

Comment: After I tried the code on several machines , I noticed that it does not work at Windows 8.1 but it works correctly at Windows 8,So any suggestions please??

Answer (score 0):

`Aes.Create` by default creates the wrapper to CryptoAPI (i. e. `AesCryptoServiceProvider`). Because CryptoAPI uses so called "cryptographic service providers" that can be installed on Windows additionally to system ones, and because also system pre-installed list of cryptographic service providers differs between Windows versions and editions, when you use `Aes.Create`, your code is actually OS-dependent. So, `Aes.Create` may produce unpredictable results, it is inevitable.

if you need full predictability, you better use other `Aes` implementations, may be `AesManaged` or any custom library. `Aes.Create` is OS-dependent by its nature.